# SMS Login using Facebook Account Kit Error on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3, account-kit

[image]

> This happens when Apple review my app. I am not able to reproduce this
>   problem.

I have tested this on actual device and **it does not have this problem** (iPhone 6 and iPhone 7)
I have also tested it on an iPad simulator and **it does not have this problem either**.

Any idea why this could happen when Apple review my app?

Actually, the right question would be

**"What could cause this problem in the first place?"**

Comment: did you solve the problem because i am having the same issue with Apple Review Team

Comment: @Hmeedo I didn't do any changes, I simply asked the review team not to use iPad to test.

Comment: thank you i uploaded the app again i hope this time they will approve the app . i will update the status when the review process is finished.

Comment: @Hmeedo, does that help? Is your app approved now?

Comment: Hello, Did you solved this problem?